# Set Window Position in VB relative to another application

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way in Visual Basic for me to position  the window of my application relative to the position of another running .EXE?

I would like to snap my Windows' right side to the left hand side of the other.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified
>   window.

Then:

```
Public Class Form1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window. 
    ''' </summary>
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowRect")>
    Shared Function GetWindowRectangle(
           ByVal [Handle] As IntPtr,
           ByRef [Rectangle] As Rectangle
    ) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Shadows Sub Load() Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim rect As New Rectangle
        Dim hwnd As IntPtr = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First.MainWindowHandle

        GetWindowRectangle(hwnd, rect)

        Me.Location = New Point(rect.X - Me.Height, rect.Y)

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you want to maintain the position even when the external process has moved/resized then you could add a Timer or other techniques to verify the window location.